# What about Google One VPN would cause Box Drive on Windows 10 to display an Excel spreadsheet with data as a blank sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vpn

A couple of times recently, a Microsoft 360 Excel spreadsheet, which had been saved to a folder on Box Drive and left open on my desktop overnight, was no longer on the desktop in the morning. There had been no Windows update to explain the disappearance.  When I went to open the spreadsheet, it appeared to be blank.

The first time this happened, I figured the spreadsheet was corrupted and resorted to a slightly outdated version that I had saved locally on the hard drive. The second time it happened, it dawned on me that the only thing I'd changed recently was setting up Google One VPN.  So I turned the VPN off and tried to open the spreadsheet, and suddenly my data was visible once again.

Searching for VPN and Box issues I've found support documents saying that the VPN could change the geographic location of the IP address which might result in slow performance, and postings where a person running a VPN was having issues and was not even able to connect to the Box support forum while the VPN was enabled, but I haven't found anything that would explain the blank Excel spreadsheet behavior.

What could cause that behavior?

P.S. I submitted a ticket to Box Support last week but haven't heard back from them.

Comment: a Microsoft 360 Excel spreadsheet, which had been saved to a folder on Box Drive    ......  DO Save and close documents (all kinds) before leaving for the day !!

Comment: Your DHCP lease on Google One was perhaps lost without renewal. Try to repeat the problem, then just turn Google One off and then back on. I wonder if that will be enough.